# Dynamically generate endpoint variable that is different for each host in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to configure a two tier application consisting of 2 servers each and I need to do it for 100 servers.  For example frontendsrv-01 needs to be configured to point to backendsrv-01 and frontendsrv-02 need to be configured to point to backendsrv-02 and so on as shown below:

```
frontendsrv-01 -> backendsrv-01
frontendsrv-02 -> backendsrv-02
....
frontendsrv-99 -> backendsrv-99
```

This is how I do it for a play with 1 server

```
endpoint_authenticated: http://{{ hostvars['backendsrv-01']['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
```

This variable is then used in template that is rendered and copied to frontendsrv-01.

Now I need to make this dynamic so that it will work on 1 or 100 servers. This is what I got and it seems to be working:

```
endpoint_authenticated: http://{{ hostvars[groups['backend_clients'][groups['frontend_clients'].index(inventory_hostname)]]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
```

While this does work it seems to be a fragile and complex solution.

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create an inventory for testing

```yaml
shell> cat create-inventory.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    indexes_str: |
      {% for i in range(1, nos|int + 1) %}
      {{ '%02d' % i }} {% endfor %}
    indexes: "{{ indexes_str.split() }}"

  tasks:

    - assert:
        that: nos is defined
        fail_msg: The variable nos (number of servers) is mandatory.

    - add_host:
        name: "frontendsrv-{{ item }}"
        groups: frontend_clients
      loop: "{{ indexes }}"

    - add_host:
        name: "backendsrv-{{ item }}"
        groups: backend_clients
        ansible_eth0:
          ipv4:
            address: "10.1.0.{{ item|int }}"
      loop: "{{ indexes }}"

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for f,b in groups.frontend_clients|zip(groups.backend_clients) %}
          {{ f }} {{ b }} {{ hostvars[b].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
          {% endfor %}
      when: debug_inventory|d(false)|bool
```

gives abridged. For example,

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook create-inventory.yml -e nos=3 -e debug_inventory=true

...
  msg: |-
    frontendsrv-01 backendsrv-01 10.1.0.1
    frontendsrv-02 backendsrv-02 10.1.0.2
    frontendsrv-03 backendsrv-03 10.1.0.3
...
```

---

Create the dictionary

```yaml
  fends_bends: "{{ dict(groups.frontend_clients|
                        zip(groups.backend_clients)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fends_bends:
    frontendsrv-01: backendsrv-01
    frontendsrv-02: backendsrv-02
    frontendsrv-03: backendsrv-03
```

and use it in the template

```yaml
  bend: "{{ fends_bends[inventory_hostname] }}"
  endpoint_authenticated: "http://{{ hostvars[bend].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing. Remove the import if you have other sources of the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- name: Create inventory for testing
  import_playbook: create-inventory.yml

- name: Test authentication of endpoints
  hosts: frontend_clients

  vars:

    fends_bends: "{{ dict(groups.frontend_clients|
                          zip(groups.backend_clients)) }}"
    bend: "{{ fends_bends[inventory_hostname] }}"
    endpoint_authenticated: "http://{{ hostvars[bend].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: fends_bends
      run_once: true
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        var: endpoint_authenticated
```

gives abridged. Remove the extra variable *nos* if you have other sources of the inventory

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e nos=3 -e debug=true

...
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [frontendsrv-01] => 
  endpoint_authenticated: http://10.1.0.1
ok: [frontendsrv-02] => 
  endpoint_authenticated: http://10.1.0.2
ok: [frontendsrv-03] => 
  endpoint_authenticated: http://10.1.0.3
...
```